# Object tracking of cable

Tags: tracking

I would like to do an object track for the front of this cable to add a dynamic hair system to it. The camera does not move, but I dont know how to get 8 trackers onto the cable tip. Is there a good workaround to get a 3d track? I am trying not to create the whole cable in 3d because it interacts with the real world.

Thanks for helping

[image]

Comment: I thought that 8 trackers was for tracking camera movement in the scene.  I've tracked an object with 4 before, I believe.

Comment: could be, I will give it a try, the documentation is a bit unclear about object tracking

Comment: There's a tutorial about object tracking [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbkXb31DrRA) which might help.

Comment: thanks, it is kind of weird. If I already have a camera solve it does not have a problem with only 3 tracks, or if it is set to tripod. Worked surprisingly well thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three points are enough. If clip is set to tripod or a camera is already solved